# angular, factory Error: AuthFactory.getUserInfo is not a function

Tags: angularjs, factory

i'm a new in Angular. I try create factory but got an Error: AuthFactory.getUserInfo is not a function. Could somebody help me?

My Code:

```
auth.factory.js:
angular.module('tsg').factory('AuthFactory', function() {
    return {
        getUserInfo: function getUserInfo(){
            console.log("AuthFactory.getUserInfo()");
            return "userInfo";
        }
      };

});
```

header.js:

```
angular.module('tsg').controller('HeaderCtrl',HeaderCtrl);

HeaderCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location','$cookieStore','AuthFactory'];
function HeaderCtrl($scope, $cookieStore, AuthFactory)
{   
    AuthFactory.getUserInfo();
    $scope.username = "UserName123";
    $scope.date = new Date();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a DI , their sequence really matters

```
HeaderCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location','$cookieStore','AuthFactory'];
function HeaderCtrl($scope, $cookieStore, AuthFactory)
```

the sequence of parameters is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have already found solution, parameters have to be the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
HeaderCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location','$cookieStore','AuthFactory'];
function HeaderCtrl($scope, $cookieStore, AuthFactory)
```

in your case `AuthFactory` instance inside your controller is not the factory you have written. It is the instance of `$location` service. You have misplaced it in the injection sequence.

When you do dependency injection follow the correct order of it as follows:

```
HeaderCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location','$cookieStore','AuthFactory'];
function HeaderCtrl($scope, $rootScope,$location,$cookieStore, AuthFactory)
```

now you factory will work as you expected.